# In Chrome’s user agent stylesheet, why use "-webkit-margin-before" et al instead of just "margin-top" et al?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, blink

`-webkit-margin-{before,after,start,end}` can be overriden by `margin-{top,bottom,left,right}` respectively. Why does Chrome’s user agent stylesheet not just use the standard `margin-` declarations?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to do with layout direction.

So `-webkit-margin-start` is like `margin-left` when the layout direction is left-to-right, but like `margin-right` when the direction is right-to-left.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jLnz2jd1/ (In Chrome, obviously)

In contexts where directionality matters, the user-agent values for these properties can be overridden. Where it doesn't matter the fallback to the standard margin properties is automatic.

Comment: Will `margin-start` et al be added to the spec?